# Dummy between another dummy

Tags: stata

I'm working in Stata wondering how to create a dummy that is between another dummy. I have time and a dummy for election years, and I want to create a dummy that indicates years in the middle between each election.

For example

[image]

Comment: Images can help -- yours is essential here to understand your problem  -- but are not so good as code given as text, which can be copied and pasted.

Comment: If one of the answers below served your purpose, it is courtesy to designate as the answer to acknowledge those who took the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

If it is always 4 years in-between each `1` in `elec` then you can use this code. If this is not the case, then you will have to provide us with more information.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int time byte elec
2000 0
2001 1
2002 0
2003 0
2004 0
2005 1
2006 0
end

*Initiate all values to 0
gen elec1 = 0

*Replace elec1 to 1 if the values in elec two rows above and two rows below is 1
replace elec1 = 1 if elec[_n-2] == 1 & elec[_n+2] == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a fair bit unexplained in this question. I read it this way and I think @TheIceBear is doing the same. (Thanks to them for the data example: OP, please note how to do it!)

1. Elections are held every four years in an area. As examples, elections were held in 2001 and 2005.
2. What is wanted is an indicator (a.k.a. dummy) for years halfway between elections. For example, 2003 is one such.

This works for the example. We notice that election years have remainder 1 on division by 4. So, the wanted years will have remainder 3.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int time byte elec
2000 0
2001 1
2002 0
2003 0
2004 0
2005 1
2006 0
end

gen test = mod(time, 4) == 1 
assert elec == test 
gen wanted = mod(time, 4) == 3 

list, sep(0)

     +-----------------------------+
     | time   elec   test   wanted |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 2000      0      0        0 |
  2. | 2001      1      1        0 |
  3. | 2002      0      0        0 |
  4. | 2003      0      0        1 |
  5. | 2004      0      0        0 |
  6. | 2005      1      1        0 |
  7. | 2006      0      0        0 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

As a test, you can check out 2007:

```
 display mod(2007, 4)
```

See [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0031) for just a few uses of the modulus, strictly the remainder.

The direct method of generating indicators as true (1) or false (0) results of a true-or-false equality or inequality is discussed at many places, such as [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/) and [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099).